# Debugger does not show the values of floats in Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: c++, xcode

Since updating Xcode, my C++ project does not show the values of any floats in the debugger: When mousing over variables or viewing their values in the variables view, floats always display a value of zero, while ints, strings and bools display correctly.

Dead simple example project here: http://www.flyingbreakfast.com/misc/Debugger-bug-Xcode-5.0.2.zip

```
float exampleFloat = 9;  // Displays 0 in debugger/variables view
int exampleInt = 9;      // Displays 9 in debugger/variables view

exampleInt += 0;         // Breakpoint on this line
```

Typing `print exampleFloat` in the LLDB prompt prints the correct value of 9, and logging the value to stdout also prints the correct values. This bug applies to all floats, not just locals.

I have checked to make sure that the project is set to build in debug, is set to optimization O0, and is not set to strip debug symbols.

This issue occurred in Xcode 5.0.1 as well.

Comment: I don't get the question, but you can try gdb instead of lldb. Or make SSCCE and bug report to Apple.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple but in the mean time this is making debugging very time consuming. Is there any workaround to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the variable in the Variables View and select "Edit Summary Format…" and check if there is anything in that text field. In my case, there was a zero in that field.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me. Are you sure there isn't something else going on?

[image]